# Probability that random subsets will have an intersection of a certain size

Tags: probability

I'm currently reading a [paper](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/wwwb/cgi-bin/tr-get.cgi/2006/MSC/MSC-2006-33.pdf) and in one of it proofs (page 17) it states the following without much explanation:

Let $l(k) = \frac{1}{2} \log^2{k}$.
Let both $A \subset [k^2]$ and $B \subset [k^2]$ be subsets of size $k \cdot \log{k}$, where $[k^2] = \{1, \dots, k^2 \}$.

The paper states that by Chernoff bound the probability that $\vert A \cap B \vert < l(k)$ is $2^{-\Omega(l(k))}$.

Could somebody explain in detail how this statement is derived and how the Chernoff bound is applied here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the way the sets are chosen (uniformly are random among sets of a specific size, instead of choosing every element to be in the set independently), this does not follow *directly* from a Chernoff bound, but due to the properties of sampling without replacement *(specifically, negative correlations, which make things even "better" in terms of concentration)* the bound will be the same as in that of sampling *with* replacement, where we can use Chernoff bounds.

Suppose each element is put independently at random in $A$ (similarly for $B$) with probability $p\stackrel{\rm def}{=}\frac{\log k}{k}$, so that $$\mathbb{E}[\lvert A\rvert] = \mathbb{E}[\lvert B\rvert] = pk^2 = k\log k$$
and the size are actually tighly concentrated around this expected value.

Let, for element $i\in[k^2]$, $X_i$ denote the indicator random variable equal to $1$ iff $i\in A\cap B$. Then, by independencce of the choices of $A$ and $B$, we have
$$
\mathbb{E}[X_i] = \Pr[i\in A\text{ and } i\in B] = p^2
$$
and we can apply a Chernoff bound to the random variable $\lvert A\cap B\rvert=\sum_{i=1}^{k^2} X_i$, which is a sum of independent random variables in $\{0,1\}$. Note that $\mathbb{E}[\lvert A\cap B\rvert] = k^2p^2 = \log^2 k = 2l(k)$.

$$
\Pr[\lvert A\cap B\rvert < l(k)]
= \Pr[\lvert A\cap B\rvert < \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}[\lvert A\cap B\rvert]] \leq e^{-\frac{1}{4}\mathbb{E}[\lvert A\cap B\rvert]/2}
=e^{-\frac{1}{4}l(k)}  = 2^{-\Omega(l(k))}
$$

Comment: thanks! It's much clearer now

Comment: Glad that helped!